# reCaptcha v2 - Textarea of 'g-recaptcha-response' not working Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha

I'm using anti-captcha Recaptchav2proxyless https://anti-captcha.com/apidoc/task-types/RecaptchaV2TaskProxyless to bypass captcha on this site https://www.rp.gob.pa/

I receive the captcha response and inserted into g-recaptcha-response after making it visible without issue but when I try to log in the element nothing happens. I get an error occured in validation.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twcdf.png)

Here is the code

```
 driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
           var containerF2 = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > app > div > div.content.px-4 > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.col-sm > form > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > iframe")));
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(containerF2);
            
            var captchaCode = "";
            var dataSiteKey = recaptchaDataSiteKey;
            captchaCode = HttpUtils.CallAntiCaptcha(driver, dataSiteKey, CaptchaType.RECAPTCHA);
            driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
            wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#g-recaptcha-response")));
            js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').setAttribute('style', 'width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: block;');");
            js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value='" + captchaCode + "';", driver.FindElement(By.Id("g-recaptcha-response")));
```

Login

```
 var username = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#itNombreUsuario")));
var password = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > app > div > div.content.px-4 > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.col-sm > form > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > input")));
                    
                    username.Clear();
                    username.SendKeys(panamaUsername);
                    password.Clear();
                    password.SendKeys(panamaPassword);

                    var submitForm = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > app > div > div.content.px-4 > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.col-sm > form > button.btn.btn-primary.btn-block"));
                    submitForm.Click();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Add the error to your question please.

Comment: @Slipoch I have edited the above. Thanks

Comment: Soz Newbie, do not link to images etc. for a non-image thing, if you cannot output the error to text or copy/paste it, maybe write it into the question please.

We need enough data in the question itself (without external links) to be able to replicate and troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: This is the exact error I'm getting
 {"element click intercepted: Element <button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-block\" type=\"submit\">...</button> is not clickable at point (667, 630). Other element would receive the click: <textarea id=\"g-recaptcha-response\" name=\"g-recaptcha-response\" class=\"g-recaptcha-response\" style=\"width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;\"></textarea>\n  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107)"}